# Rest service issue with attachment call from OSB Proxy/pipeline service - multipart/form-data;boundary=--<> payload empty

Tags: rest, multipartform-data, attachment, payload, osb

We have a requirement to send an attachment file to external restBMC service using content-type `multipart/form-data;boundary=--<boundary value>`

When we run using the business service it is working fine, but from pipeline or from source call, the payload is returning as null/ empty in the logs while calling the business service.

what is the issue here? which Content-Type do we need to pass in transport header or what to be changed in order to support the attachment data to external service.

```
[OSB Tracing] Outbound request was sent.


Payload =

<empty>
```

Here we are getting response status 500.

when run from business service it has payload sent, showing in the logs and respose status is 201.

```
Payload = 
payload = 
<multipart/form-data>
```

OSB Multipart/form-data issue in OSB for sending attachment in Json payload